# How to concatenate a derived array

Tags: mongodb

This is my Database schema:

[image]

This is retrieving the reviews sorted by creation date desc and is working:

```
db.films.findOne(
        { _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596") },
        {
          title: 1,
          reviews: {
            $sortArray: { input: "$reviews", sortBy: { creationdate: -1 } },
          },
        }
      );
```

I tried a test here with concatenating 2 arrays from the Database and it's working:

```
db.films.findOne(
        { _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596") },
        {
          title: 1,
          reviews: {
            $concatArrays: ["$reviews", "$reviews"],
          },
        }
      );
```

What I'm trying to do is combine the two, concatenate `$reviews` with the sorted reviews array from the first statement as follows:

```
db.films.findOne(
        { _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596") },
        {
          title: 1,
          reviews: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$reviews",
              $sortArray: { input: "$reviews", sortBy: { creationdate: -1 } },
            ],
          },
        }
      );
```

It isn't working, there's a syntax error. Could I do this? any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there's a syntax error

It would be helpful if you would provide that syntax error. By pasting your query into mongoplayground, we can see from [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dbxw9r6ZHqa) that the error is:

```
Unknown type: '$sortArray: {'
```

This is because that second argument to `$concatArrays` (the one in which you are modifying the earlier array) needs to itself be an object. Wrapping it in curly brackets resolves the issue:

```
db.films.findOne({
  _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596")
},
{
  title: 1,
  reviews: {
    $concatArrays: [
      "$reviews",
      {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$reviews",
          sortBy: {
            creationdate: -1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4MT-V_wSJ2Q)

It's unclear if you want to duplicate the `reviews` array as is written in your question, but the answer to the question itself is "*yes, you can concatenate the two arrays by resolving your syntax error.*"

Comment: ok thanks. You forgot to wrap in curly brackets in your reply but did so in playground and it's working

Comment: Haha, oops! Pasted from the wrong demo. Thanks for catching, I've fixed it in the answer for posterity